# How to hide a radio button on all browsers except Internet explorer?

Tags: html, css

I've code like given below:

```
<label>
   <input type="hidden" name="styless" value="9">
   <input type="radio" style="display:none" >Qwerty
</label>
```

This is working fine on all browsers except Internet Explorer. How do I display the radio button in the IE browser, and make it remain hidden on other browsers?

What happens in IE is when I click on "Qwerty", the click event is not fired.
So i want to remove `display:none` in IE only.

Comment: You can't sniff out browser types (reliably), except with IE conditional comments, which only work on IE9 and below.

Comment: @silviagreen Why do you assume he uses jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Generally **you shouldn't try to make page behavior browser-specific**. I would argue that a much better solution would be to make the `"Qwerty"` text click act the same way on all browsers.

You can do it with JavaScript - wrap the text in a `<span>` element, and give it an `onclick` event which would check your radio button. To find the radio button reliably, you should give it an `id` attribute. Then call `preventDefault` on the click event, to avoid any unwanted behavior *which may or may not happen otherwise*.

Your final HTML should look like this:

```
<label>
   <input type="hidden" name="styless" value="9">
   <input type="radio" style="display:none" id="qwerty-radio-box">
   <span onclick="document.getElementById('qwerty-radio-box').checked = true; event.preventDefault();">Qwerty</span>
</label>
```

In your question, you didn't mention whether or not your project already has a JavaScript codebase. If it does, you should move the JavaScript code there, instead of keeping it in this `onclick` event attribute. If it doesn't, and this is the only usage, I'd say it's fine leaving it here.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.browser property, you can do it using  [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) plugin (for JQuery >= 1.9 - in earlier versions you can just use it) and then do something like this:

```
if (!$.browser.msie){
// do something
}
```